# Kitchen countertop cracked

Tags: repair, kitchens

Last week I paid Home Depot for a kitchen sink install. They sent out Delta Mechanical(subcontractor) to uninstall the existing sink and installed the new one. The uninstall was smooth but when they were installing the new sink I didn't see as I was in the living room but I was about 25ft away and heard one of the installers pound the new sink into place. I went over to look and saw 3 cracks around the new sink that were not there before. They sent a countertop specialist out to look at it and he just "repaired" it by putting superglue inside the cracks and filling the surface with epoxy then coloring it with a sharpie but I can still see the cracks afterward. I will attach the before-repair and after-repair photos below. My concern is that will this now be a weak point where it will eventually break apart since they are now 3 separate pieces and please tell me if that is an adequate repair in your opinion. Thank you

Update:
I spoke with a district manager of HD, she got their insurance company to issue a denial of damages because in the contract they state "chips or cracks on existing countertops may occur when removing/lifting drop-in sinks". This is very frustrating, I'm planning on contacting corporate but I was told it will get kick back down to that manager but I will do it anyways. I also told her the repair is inadequate as the damages is still very visible and she told me it was the best they could have done, I need to get some professional licensed countertop contractor to chime in whether the repair was adequate or not. Does anyone have any advice for me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unacceptable. After HomeDepot mangled up a replacement window job, I’ll never use them again. Once bitten, twice shy.

Comment: @jsotola to judge who's being reasonable in a situation. This is akin to an AITA post; OP doesn't have enough experience to know what is or isn't reasonable. And because they're a good human being they don't want to mistakenly be the unreasonable party in the conversation, so they're asking a bunch of informed strangers with no monetary stakes in the answer where the "reasonable" line is.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, none of this is acceptable. IMO no-one involved in this should be calling themselves a tradesperson. Hammering a sink in to a space it doesn't fit in to was only going to end one way. There are proper tools for cutting stone counters, but, you know, *that's so much effort*! And repairing it with superglue and a sharpie sounds like what I'd see on 5-Minute crafts or DIY hack joke videos on Facebook

Comment: I sure hope the underside is slotted for metal rods...  OP, you may need a granite counter specialist to repair that (make HD pay for it).

Comment: **No.** "Last week I paid Home Depot for a kitchen sink install." - Not *your* problem.

Comment: Agree that this isn't acceptable. For what it's worth, HD knows they pay peanuts and frequently get monkeys, so shouldn't push back at remedying the issue. If the local store does push back, escalate as high as you can get in the store, then involve the corporate offices. Be very clear to the store level people about your intentions to escalate without sounding too threatening.

Comment: Please verify what I think: it's a chipboard worktop, with a plastic covering.

Comment: Like it or not, this is an opinion question bordering on a legal one. It does not seek to solve a home improvement problem, but to resolve a home improvement _contract_ problem. Voting to close.

Comment: If its plastic covering that is cracked, then there is not much point in pursuing. But if its stone, then this strategy has worked for me against a car dealer when I purchased a new car, dents thrown in for free.  I said that I would be out there every weekend with a few friends and placards.  They replaced the car.

Answer (score 23):

The cracks are absolutely noticeable.  The job was not done correctly.

Demand a new counter or to have it repaired to your satisfaction. But do it with a controlled temper and speak to a store manager or assistant manager.  Show your pictures.

I have had instances similar and have had things rectified to my satisfaction by both the big box stores.

Comment: I think this falls under what stores do.  You break it, you buy it.  New sinks should fit in the hole.  Pounding is not proper sink installation.  Maybe with rough framing work I might use a sledge as a mistake fixer.

Comment: ...and if they refuse, proceed through the courts. This is 100% not acceptable.

Comment: Absolutely. Look through the contract you signed, there will be something in there about the standard of work and guarantees (as well as disclaimers and such). They will try to weasel out of it by claiming that there were "pre-existing defects in the countertop" or whatever else they can think of, *don't let them*. This damage was a direct result of their (contractor's) unprofessional workmanship.

Comment: @DoktorJ - if there *were* pre-existing defects, so much more reason to reject the job. And insist a different team comes to re-install.

Comment: Exactly,  if defects were there, any moron would not try to pound on the sink to install it.

Comment: To add to the above, if there were existing defects, the burden is on them to prove it; if they were competent tradespeople, they would have identified and documented any pre-existing defects before commencing work or, as @Tim said, refused the job.

Comment: The above three comments make great points, but that won't stop HD or their contractor from trying to weasel out of responsibility! Hold their feet to the fire!

Comment: I would recommend going to the store _in person_ to talk to the manager directly. Hold your fire, be as reasonable and accommodating as possible, but be insistent on getting this fixed on their dime. From everything I've heard, HD managers have _huge_ leeway on what they're allowed to do, and if you appear in person and are calm and reasonable, the local manager may just make sure it gets made right _without_ having to go to court about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Update: I spoke with a district manager of HD, she got their insurance company to issue a denial of damages because in the contract they state "chips or cracks on existing countertops may occur when removing/lifting drop-in sinks".

And what does that have to do with anything? It's not your insurance, it's HD's insurance. Home Depot got *their* claim denied. You still have a claim with Home Depot. Just go to small claims court.

The way big-box stores work is that they underpay their subcontractors, who then are always working in a hurry to squeeze some money out a bad deal. When things go wrong, the store does a charge back on the subcontractor. The sub then quits and HD gets another sucker sub. But none of this is your problem. They broke your countertop and you are owed a replacement.